# Using row as a Slider for Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a row of years `2016, 2017, 2018, 2019`. And each row there is a value, with some no value. And some of them, all of the year have a value. I want to create a pivot table with a slicer that can pinpoint the year that I want to see.

[image]

The row before this is Location, customer, Product. For those, I can easily make a slicer in Pivot. But for the years I do not know how.

I want to make another slicer but for years only.

Any ideas as to how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Sample data would help, perhaps a screenshot..?

Comment: Yes, I just uploaded a picture.

Comment: While create Slicer, Excel asks to select Column to use as Slicer,, so that you can say value in Row or Column can be used as Slicer ro PT!!